# File Not Found Matplotlib Line Plot with 2 lines

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

Thank you in advance for your help!

Data for [minot_air](https://github.com/the-datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/blob/master/minotDailyAirTemp.csv)

Data for [minot_soil](https://github.com/the-datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/blob/master/Minot_20CM_Daily.csv)

**I am trying to graph two datasets to one plot and I want it to look somewhat like the first image. The problem is that I keep getting these errors when I run my code (provided below):**

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\minotDailyAirTemp.csv does not exist: 'C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\minotDailyAirTemp.csv'

**Why might I be getting these errors? I have checked and that is indeed the location of each of the files.
Images two and three show them on my desktop as well as show the file hierarchy:**

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# data import
minot_air_temp = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\minotDailyAirTemp.csv")
minot_soil_temp = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\Minot_20CM_Daily.csv")

air_temp = pd.read_csv(minot_air_temp, header = 0, index_col = 0,
                         parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
soil_temp = pd.read_csv(minot_soil_temp, header = 0, index_col = 0,
                       parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

# plot both overlayed
ax = air_temp.plot(figsize=(20,10))
soil_temp.plot(ax=ax)
```

Error 1:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-f1b5480c283a> in <module>
      4 
      5 # data import
----> 6 minot_air_temp = 
pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\minotDailyAirTemp.csv")
      7 minot_soil_temp = 
pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\Minot_20CM_Daily.csv")
      8 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, 
usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, 
true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, 
na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, 
parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, 
cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, 
lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, 
encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, 
low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    446 
    447     # Create the parser.
--> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    449 
    450     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, 
engine, **kwds)
    878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    879 
--> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    881 
    882     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, 
engine)
   1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1113         if engine == "c":
-> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1115         else:
   1116             if engine == "python":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, 
**kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in 
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File 
C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop\minotDailyAirTemp.csv does not exist: 
'C:\\Users\\Xavier\\Desktop\\minotDailyAirTemp.csv'
```

Comment: Please format the error traceback as code so it's minimally legible

Comment: Please create an MCVE. If you read the error message, you will see that the problem has nothing to do with matplotlib or other library.

Comment: I had it in a folder  named Graphs and I would get a FileNotFound error

Comment: I then also tried it directly from my desktop and got the same result

Answer (score 0):

In the images you included it appears that the files are directly in the Desktop directory and not in a Graphs folder.

Should the file path be “C:\Users\Xavier\Desktop”?

Comment: I tried it in a folder named Graphs first, then I tried it from the desktop. The file path you are seeing is from when I tried it from within the folder

Comment: I changed the code in the question so that the directories match. I was just trying to show that I have tried multiple directories